# Can German citizens enter Mexico on one-way tickets?

Tags: mexico, german-citizens, proof-of-onward-travel

We are in Miami, Florida and after two weeks we have a flight to Mexico. We have already purchased our flight tickets from Miami, Florida to Mexico City which is only one way. We are planning to stay in Mexico for two months and not sure after two months we might be going back to USA or some other South American countries.

Is it OK if we just enter Mexico with one-way airline tickets?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question cannot be answered because any answers would speculate on the decision of Mexican Immigration at the Point of Entry.  Mexico, like many countries, does not *require* an onward ticket, but having one helps diminish any concern you will overstay.  So, the best advice is to be able to demonstrate you intend to leave within 180 days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it OK if we just enter Mexico with one way airline ticket?

No, you cannot enter Mexico with one way ticket. As a German citizen, you are entitled to stay in Mexico for up to 180 days. It is clearly written in Mexico Consulate in Frankfurt website that you must have a proof of return/onward ticket along with other requirements which you are supposed to meet at immigration. The website is in German but I have translated into English.

Source: [Mexico Consulate Frankfurt](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/frankfurt/index.php/servicios/visa/visas-aleman)

> My nationality is not in the list of countries visumplichtige
>
> There is no visa required; Please include present at entry:
>
> - Valid passport, the passport must have at time of travel will be    valid for at least six months.
> - Filled entry form for tourists FMM (get this on the plane) and the    presentation thereof in the immigration department at the time of
>     entry into Mexico.
> - The local officials may also request the following: **Return ticket,    hotel reservations, and other travel documents.**

Further [Timatic](http://www.qatarairways.com/pk/en/visa-and-passport-requirements.page) confirms entry could be refused for not holding return/onward ticket.
National Germany (DE)           /Embarkation USA (US)
Destination Mexico (MX)

Mexico (MX)

Passport required.
- Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
  valid on arrival.
- Warning: if departing from the USA (regardless of any

destination passport exemptions), a valid passport and/or

accepted departure document For details, click here is required by the
  US immigration authorities.

Passport Exemptions:

- Passengers with an emergency or a temporary passport. 
  Admission and Transit Restrictions:
- Passengers with a non-machine readable passport are not
  allowed to enter or transit Mexico.
  -This does not apply to passengers with an emergency or a
  temporary passport.

Visa required, except for Nationals of Germany with a normal,emergency or temporary passport for a maximum stay of 180 days.
Minors:
- Passport not required for alien minors (up to/incl.17 years
  of age) registered in their parent/guardian passport,
  provided traveling with the passport holder. 
- All minors under 14 years of age, when traveling alone,
  should be met by an adult. 
Warning:
- **Visitors not holding return/onward tickets For details, click here could be refused entry.**

Therefore you should get a return/onward flight ticket along with hotel reservation and passport must be valid for at least 6 months.